# Kinect paint - hand tracking c#, kinect SDK 1.7

Tags: c#, wpf, sdk, kinect

I am trying to make some simple app which allows you to paint on canvas with your right hand.
Fortunately I know how to make painting function but I have a little problem with other thing.
As you know SDK provides you to use a control named KinectRegion which has KinectCursor which is the representation of user's hand.

The problem is that I don't know why when I am trying to paint something my painting path starts in different position than my KinectCursor is ?

I don't have this problem when I use my own right hand mapping function but in that case I can't use other things like KinectCircleButton because I don't have KinectRegion.

Anyone know how to get or to map KinectCursor position(x,y) from KinectRegion ?

visualisation of my problem:
[IMG]http://i58.tinypic.com/iqgemt.png[/IMG]

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on the similar project on painting with Kinect. Actually the position you need is in the HandPointer. You can get the position of your hand relative to UIElement by a method called GetPosition(UIElement element) which obviously takes that element as parameter.

An example of using the method looks like this:

```
public partial class MainWindow
{
    public Point position;

    public MainWindow
    {
        KinectRegion.AddHandPointerMoveHandler(this, OnHandPointerMove);
    }

    private void OnHandPointerMove(object sender, HandPointerEventArgs e)
    {
        position = e.HandPointer.GetPosition(myCanvas);
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your interest but GetPosition method will not give me the HandPointer X and Y coordinates on the screen

Comment: Position is saved and updated in the variable "position" each time you move hand. If you want to see it on the screen, create a label in your main window and update its content in the same event handler with "myLabel.Content = position.X + "," + position.Y;"

Comment: I think you don't understand me because if I use CoordinateMapper method I will have X and Y values of my right hand on the screen( for example in the left top corner it will be 0,0 and in the right bottom corner it will be 1366,768) but X and Y values of HandPointer will be in the left top corner 0,0 and in the right bottom corner 1,1

Comment: Well, post here some code you're using. I cannot tell You more if I cannot see your CoordinateMapper method. But as far as I know KinectRegion automatically sets the bounds of the interaction zone and map it to your computer screen. I also tried to do that and it worked.

Comment: {CoordinateMapper mapper = sensorK.CoordinateMapper;

var point = mapper.MapSkeletonPointToColorPoint(rightHand.Position, sensorK.ColorStream.Format);}

Comment: I see.. Well, I personally don't use CoordinateMapper in my project, so I guess I cannot help you with that. But I've found something like this: http://pterneas.com/2014/06/06/kinect-cursor-for-hand-tracking/ Try to look at his code how he uses his KinectCursor with the mapper. And good luck with your project.

Answer (score 0):

Now the thing is your hand position and kinect hand position has a gap in both X and Y. Try to make these gaps zero. Then your hand will exactly map the painting point. For example output x,y coordinates at once for both hand point and painting brush point. and get the individual gap for both x coordinates and y coordinates. now these difference should be deducted form x and y respectively. So then your hand and paint brush points will map accordingly.